# Count HTTP method invocations by status using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I have a RESTfull application written in Java 8 on Spring Boot 1.5.2.

I would like to collect statistics for the application usage, and i would like to get counters for tupples of (HTTP method, endpoint pattern, HTTP status).

I couldn't find an approach that covers my needs

---

### Example

If my service receives 7 calls:

```
200 GET /user 
400 POST /user
200 POST /user
200 GET /user/67
200 GET /user/90
200 GET /user/90/message
500 POST /user/90/message
```

I expect to collect:

```
GET /user 200 - 1
POST /user 400 - 1
POST /user 200 - 1
GET /user/{userId} 200 - 2
GET /user/{userId}/message 200 - 1
POST /user/{userId}/message 500 - 1
```

---

### Possible approaches I've tried

1. Spring actuator metrics - Spring actuator collects data about method invocations and groups the counters by status.

   - Example:

     > {
     >          "counter.status.200.user": 86,
     >          "counter.status.200.user.userId": 32,
     >          "counter.status.200.user.userId.message": 69
     >         }
   - The drawbacks: HTTP method is not being grouped by the HTTP method
2. Spring filter - Found [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-api-metrics) Baeldung example that collects the metrics by the tupple (HTTP method, endpoint, HTTP status).

   - The drawback: It uses the actual endpoint rather than the endpoint-pattern, which means that *GET /user/1* and *GET /user/2* will be counted separately.

Comment: Using the filter from Baeldung, you are free to analyse the request string as you want to. Just adapt the code to make "/user/1" and "/user/2" count for the same endpoint. You are the best to know which parts of your URL pattern are fixed keywords and which are placeholders for IDs.

Comment: I have around 50 different endpoints and it's gonna grow.
It is not maintainable as i see it, it should be done automatically.